# Find device in windows registry

Tags: c, windows, pci

I have to do certain operation on controller present in my system. For that I have to find the device in the registry and open the file associated with it. I know the device is in the under Scsi in the registry. Initially I thought I'l find the device by the driver name associated with the device but there are cases when the driver name is same if the device is of same category and same manufacturer.
Is it possible to get the PCI address of the device somehow or any other method to do it?

Comment: You are probably going to have to identify the device by Vendor ID and Device ID (VID/PID). I believe all devices have those pair of ID's tyo allow drivers etc. to recognise them.

Comment: Hey the vendor id and the device is are the same